# Jquery grid loading text disable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I used a jqGrid for display the call details it will refresh or reload with every seconds. but when it reload it is showing Loading... like that I don't want to show that message every second.

So I need to disable the loading text (Loading...) and the UI of JQuery grid while loading/reloading

my code is :

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid(
{
    url: "activeCallDetails.html",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype:'post',
    width:930,
    height: 200,
    shrinkToFit:true,
    loadtext : '',
    jsonReader: 
    { 
        repeatitems : false, id: "0" 
    },
    multiselect: false,
    viewrecords: true,
    headtitles: true,
    paging: true,
    loadtext : '',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20],
    pager: jQuery("#page"),
    loadonce:false,
    caption: "Active Call List"
  }).navGrid('#page',
  {
        edit:false,
        add:false,
        del:false,
        search:false
  });
```

but there is a small box without text  while loading.

Any solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To disable loading message you can use the following [jqGrid option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions):

```js
loadui: 'disable'
```